# Convert Python list to pandas Series

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe, series

What is the method to convert a Python list of strings to a `pd.Series` object?

(pandas Series objects can be converted to list using `tolist()` method--but how to do the reverse conversion?)

Comment: @smci this is really embarrassing for me, a question from the time when I was a newbie. You have edited it already, looks good now.

Comment: HypotheticalNinja: it's a perfectly good canonical question on an important basic topic.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I understand that your list is in fact a list of lists

```
import pandas as pd

thelist = [ ['sentence 1'], ['sentence 2'], ['sentence 3'] ]
df = pd.Series( (v[0] for v in thelist) )
```

Comment: from your edits and comments, I understand that the list you're talking about is a list of lists. you have to make it 1D to make the Series. I edited my post to show how to do that with a generator.

Comment: it was simple.. df = pd.Series(data) .. automatically converted the whole text into a dataframe object.. thanks.. you can edit your post and include this too,for others to benefit.. :)

Comment: ok, still not sure about what a sentence is in your case, but I'm happy I could help anyway :-) - cheers

Answer (score 42):

To convert the list `myList` to a Pandas series use:

```
mySeries = pd.Series(myList)
```

This is also one of the basic ways for creating a series from a list in Pandas.

Example:

```
myList = ['string1', 'string2', 'string3']                                                                                                                
mySeries = pd.Series(myList)                                                                                                                             
mySeries                                                                                                                                                 
# Out: 
# 0    string1
# 1    string2
# 2    string3
# dtype: object
```

Note that Pandas will guess the data type of the elements of the list because a series doesn't admit mixed types (contrary to Python lists). In the example above the inferred datatype was `object` (the Python `string`) because it's the most general and can accommodate all other data types (see [data types](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/basics.html#dtypes)).

It's possible to specify a data type when creating a series:

```
myList= [1, 2, 3] 

# inferred data type is integer
pd.Series(myList).dtype                                                                                                                        
# Out:
# dtype('int64')

myList= ['1', 2, 3]                                                                                                                                     

# data type is object  
pd.Series(myList).dtype                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
# Out: 
# dtype('O')
```

One can specify `dtype` as integer:

```
myList= ['1', 2.2, '3']
mySeries = pd.Series(myList, dtype='int')  
mySeries.dtype                                                                                                                                 
# Out:
# dtype('int64')
```

But this will work only if all elements in the list can be casted to the desired data type.

Answer (score 11):

```
import pandas as pd
sentence_list = ['sentence 1', 'sentence 2', 'sentence 3', 'sentence 4']
print("List of Sentences: \n", sentence_list)
sentence_series = pd.Series(sentence_list)
print("Series of Sentences: \n", sentence_series)
```

[Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.html#)

Even if `sentence_list` is a list of list, this code still converts a list to Pandas Series object.

Answer (score 2):

`pd.Series(l)` actually works on almost any type of list and it returns Series object:

```
import pandas as pd
l = [ ['sentence 1'], ['sentence 2'], ['sentence 3'] ] #works
l = ['sentence 1', 'sentence 2', 'sentence 3'] #works
l = numpy.array(['sentance 1', 'sentance2', 'sentance3'], dtype='object') #works

print(l, type(l))
ds = pd.Series(l)
print(ds, type(ds))
```

---

```
0    sentence 1
1    sentence 2
2    sentence 3
dtype: object <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```